# Find a value that matches the date and amount between two tables

Tags: sql, mariadb

If the date and amount of the two tables match,
 how can I compare the amount with the other date if the amount is not on the true date?

condition1
True if the date and amount match

Condition 2.
If you don't have the same amount for that date, look for the amount that corresponds to the previous date, and if you have a matching amount

condition3
False if the amount does not match

I have 2 tables, one for t1 and another one for their t2. Those are mariaDB

t1 table:

```
  id      | date  |     cash_amount_received
----------------------------------
  1        2020-04-01      7000
  2        2020-04-29      1000
  3        2020-04-29      2000
  4        2020-04-29      3000
  5        2020-04-29      4000
  6        2020-04-29      5000
  7        2020-04-29      6000
  8        2020-04-29      10000
```

t2 table:

```
  id      |    date  |    amount
----------------------------------
  1             2020-04-29       1000
  2             2020-04-29       2000
  3             2020-04-29       3000
  4             2020-04-29       4000
  5             2020-04-29       5000
  6             2020-04-29       5000
  7             2020-04-29       7000
```

I want to achieve this result:

```
 id     |  cash_amount_received    |    amount|    result
-----------------------------------------------------
  1          7000                    7000          true
  2          1000                    1000          true
  3          2000                    2000          true
  4          3000                    3000          true
  5          4000                    4000          true
  6          5000                    5000          true
  7          6000                    null          false
  8          10000                   null          false
  9          null                    5000          false
```

How should I fill out the query?
I have no idea. Help me.

Comment: This is difficult. You want iteration here. Let's say t1 has `2020-04-01 | 1000` and `2020-04-02 | 1000` and t2 has `2020-04-03 | 1000`, `2020-04-04 | 1000`, and `2020-04-05 | 1000`. Then condition 1 (same date and amount exists) is never met and condition 2 (earlier date and amount exists) is always met. But you probably want this result: `1000 | 1000 | true`, `1000 | 1000 | true`, `null | 1000 | false`...

Comment: ...Same for t1 having `2020-04-01 | 1000` twice and t2 having it thrice. Condition 1 (same date and amount exists) is always met, but you probably want again `1000 | 1000 | true`, `1000 | 1000 | true`, `null | 1000 | false`. I.e. you want to iterate through your data, pick every match and remove the rows in order to only look at the remaining data that has no match yet. While this may be possible with some recursive queries, **I don't recommend doing this in SQL. Use a programming language instead.** Select all rows from both tables and then loop through them to do your matching.

Comment: The IDs are confusing by the way. Where do you get the result IDs from for instance? I suppose we can completely ignore all IDs? They have no meaning for the stated task, or have they?

Comment: You haven't explained how the ids are assigned.  Although I have ideas on how to handle the conditions you specify, without knowing what the ids mean, I'm not willing to even hazard an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create 2 queries:
One for all the sums reconciled
One for all the sums not reconciled.

Reconciled

```
SELECT t1.date, t1.cash_amount_received
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.date = t2.date AND t1.cash_amount_received = t2.amount
ORDER BY t1.date, t1.cash_amount_received
```

Not reconciled

```
SELECT t1.date AS t1_date, t1.cash_amount_received, t2.date AS t2_date, t2.amount
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.date != t2.date OR t1.cash_amount_received != t2.amount
ORDER BY t1.date, t1.cash_amount_received
```